# What constitutes giving legal advice?

Tags: united-states, advice

On sites such as this one, people are often concerned about non-lawyers "giving legal advice" or "practicing law without a license".  What, exactly, constitutes such actions?  I'm particularly interested in the situation in the United States, since that's where the StackExchange servers are.

Comment: Related: http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/a/169/10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends highly on which jurisdiction you're referring to. This is one of the areas where it varies state to state. "Practicing law" is not generally defined in statute, but the [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practice_of_law) defines it as (emphasis mine):

> **giving legal advice** to clients, drafting legal documents for clients, and representing clients in legal negotiations and court proceedings such as lawsuits, and is applied to the professional services of a lawyer or attorney at law, barrister, solicitor, or civil law notary.

Wikipedia defines [Legal advice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_advice) as

> the giving of a professional or formal opinion regarding the substance or procedure of the law in relation to a particular factual situation.

and displays the following enforcement provision (emphasis mine):

> Criminal laws and enforcement of "Unauthorized Practice of Law (UPL)" statutes is the organized bar's preferred method. Thus, New Jersey has a law which makes it a “**disorderly persons offense**” to knowingly to engage in the unauthorized practice of law, and a “**crime in the fourth degree**” to commit UPL if one (a) creates a false impression that one is a lawyer; (b) derives a benefit from UPL, or (c) causes an injury by UPL.

See also [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL), which has some information about usage on the Internet:

> The case law standard for determining what comments cross the line is generally "the application of law to facts specific to an individual seeking legal advice".